# How is it possible to force \$v(t)=\cos(t)\$ as voltage input to a fully discharged capacitor?

Tags: capacitor, basic

Let initial charge on capacitor  \$Q=0\$ and say \$v(t)=\cos(t)\$ is applied for one period(\$2\pi\$ seconds) across the capacitor. Then the current will be \$i(t) = C\cos(t+\pi/2)\$. Clearly the initial current is also \$0\$.

So at \$t=0\$, the charge on capacitor is \$0\$ and the current is \$0\$.
How can the initial voltage be \$\cos(0)=1V\$ ? How is it possible to have any voltage with \$0\$ charge? Doesn't this fail \$Q=CV\$ ?

Comment: Your formula is for steady state. The current at *t(0)* will be a transient and if you've got an ideal voltage source you'll have an invalid condition because there is no resistance in your circuit. There will be a divide by zero somewhere in your maths.

Comment: At \$t=0^+\$, the current will have the form of a delta function.

Comment: You mean `ideally` the capacitor builds charge instantly so that \$Q=CV\$ and \$i=0\$ don't fail at \$t=0^+\$?

Comment: Oh right, practically putting a small resistor would fix the issue. Then the capacitor will have \$0V\$ initially and take time building up the charge. THank you so much I get it:))

Comment: If v(t) is cos, then the current will be sin(t), not cos(t)

Comment: @Neil_UK fixed it ty :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are missing is that your input is not a pure cosine. You are implicitly assuming an input of zero for all \$t < 0\$. Hence

$$v = u(t) \cos(t),$$

where \$u\$ is the step function. This complicates things a bit. Applying the properties of the derivative of a product and using the fact that \$\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}t} = \delta\$ yields

$$i = C \delta(t) \cos(t) - C u(t) \sin(t).$$

So what you have is

$$i =
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if } t<0, \\
C \delta(t) & \text{if } t = 0, \\
-C\sin(t) & \text{if } t > 0.
\end{cases}
$$

So at \$t=0\$ the capacitor charges. This can be seen by integrating the current around the origin. Hence

$$Q(0) = \lim_{\Delta t \to 0} \int_{-\infty}^{\Delta t} C\delta(t)\ \mathrm{d}t = C.$$

Thus \$Q = CV\$ is still satisfied.

Comment: so the unit step function ensures the required \$Q=\int_{0^-}^{0^+} C\delta t\, dt = C\$ charge is built up instantly at \$t=0\$. Brilliant! Thank you so much:)

Comment: @beccaboo Yes. See my edit for more information.

Comment: You cannot change the voltage on a capacitor from 0 V to 1 V in an instant of time because a capacitor stores energy in an electric field.  The energy stored is \$\frac{1}{2}CV^2\$.

Comment: @skvery Yes, I’m familiar with the two capacitor paradox. However in this simpler model inductance is ignored and we pretend that the current can be infinite. It is just a first order approximation, but it is useful in certain situations.

Comment: @user110971 I do not think you understand the issue.  Read my answer.

Comment: @skvery I understand the issue perfectly well, as it is covered in virtually all EEE courses. I gave my answer with the level of the question in mind. You can of course add an inductance and a resistance in series, which will give you a more accurate model.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that the capacitor stores energy in a electric field and \$i(t) = C \frac{dv(t)}{dt}\$.

If at \$t = 0, \ \cos(t) =1\$ then \$\frac{dv(t)}{dt} = \infty\$ so the current is not 0 A.

If however \$v(t) = \sin(\omega t)\$ then \$i(t) = C\frac{sin(t)}{dt} = \cos(t)\  \forall\ t\ge 0\$ then at \$t = 0,\ i(0)  = \cos(0) = 1\ A\$.

In simpler terms \$i(t) = c\frac{\Delta v(t)}{\Delta t}\$ and this means that you cannot change the voltage in the capacitor at \$t=0\$ from \$0\ V\$ to \$1\ V\$ at that instant.  Therefore \$v(t) = \sin(t)\$ is simpler to analyse from \$t=0\$. In the case where \$v(t) = \sin(t), i(t) = \cos(t)\$.

Comment: Oh right! At \$t = 0\$, if the voltage jumps from \$0V\$ to \$1V\$, then the current has to be infinity, not \$0\$. Awesome! Thank you so much for such clear explanation :))